# Выделение элемента listbox wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть listboxitem, на котором присутствует label, button. Как можно по нажатию на кнопку выделить listboxitem, содержащий нажатую кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Button Margin="20,5">Click me</Button>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Button Margin="20,5">Click me</Button>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```